# How to turn the Time Spent field visible on other pages besides Task Detail?

Tags: rally

Is it possible to add the "Time Spent" field to other pages besides the Task Detail page?
Like showing it on the Iteration Status page, for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Track -> Iteration Status Page is not customizable. This is a popular feature request for this page. I'd encourage you to vote for the following Rally Idea:

[Add ability to customize columns in Iteration Status grid](https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D1976)

On the [Rally Ideas site](https://ideas.rallydev.com).

To enhance visibility of this feature for Rally's product owners.